# overlay to be displayed only once using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an overlay when the page is loaded But only once, But I am having form in that page when the user save some information in Database again the same over lay is displayed I want that overlay to be displayed only once till the window is closed.

I am using cookies to perform the same but I am not able to to do so, I have seen that code somewhere on internet, But its not working I don't know what mistake I am making

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (document.cookie != "shown") {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn("fast", function () {
      $(".box").animate({"top": "200px"});
    });
    $("img").click(function () {
      $(".box").animate({"top": "-250px"}, function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut("fast");
      });
    });
    document.cookie = "shown";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.cookie` stores cookie in a `;` separated list format. Use a `search` function to see if shown exists inside it:

```
if( document.cookie.search("shown") == -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Checking if cookie exists** method:

```
function cookieExists(name) {
 return document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=") == 0 ? true : document.cookie.indexOf("; " + name + "=")!=-1
}
```

usage :

```
cookieExists("Your_cookie_name")
```

**Setting cookie** method:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
   document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

usage for setting cookie (for ten years):

```
setCookie("YOUR_COOKIE_NAME","true",10*365)
```

removing cookie:

```
setCookie("YOUR_COOKIE_NAME","",0)
```

**Finally:** 1.)You must check if he has cookie and if hasn't show overlay.2.) Than add cookie when he close overlay, absctact code:

**1.)**

```
if(!cookieExists("Mark_overlay")){
//SHOW OVERLAY
}
```

**2.)**

```
//on overlay closing
 setCookie("Mark_overlay","true",10*365)
```